# c++ opengl nvoglv32.dll error

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

I have a sprite class to handle initializing a sprite and drawing it but i keep getting this error `Exception thrown at 0x68ECC760 (nvoglv32.dll)` this seems to be mainly because of `_vboID` and `_vertNum` I'm not exactly sure what is wrong with them though, here's the source code for it

```
void Sprite::init(int vertNum, float r, Shape shape) {
    _vertNum = vertNum;
    if (_vboID = 0) {
        glGenBuffers(1, &_vboID);
    }
    std::vector<Vertex> vertexData(vertNum);
    if (shape == Shape::CIRCLE) {
        for (int i = 0; i < vertNum; i++) {
            vertexData[i].setPosition(r*cos(i), r*sin(i));
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < _vertNum; i++) {
        vertexData[i].setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    }
    glBindBuffer(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, _vboID);
    glBufferData(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, sizeof(vertexData), vertexData.data(), GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, 0);
}

void Sprite::draw() {
    //bind buffer array
    glBindBuffer(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, _vboID);

    //use first vertex attrib array
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    //pointer to vertices location
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, position));
    //pointer to vertices color
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, color));

    //Draw the 6 vertices to the screen
    glDrawArrays(GL_POLYGON, 0, _vertNum);

    //Disable the vertex attrib array. This is not optional.
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    //Unbind the VBO
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

Comment: Which exception is thrown? Please be as precise as possible.

Comment: @JanHenke sorry about not including this in the original post but here its is `Exception thrown at 0x692CC760 (nvoglv32.dll) in Flora.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.` that's all that visual studio gives me.

Comment: Your are trying to dereference a NULL pointer. Make sure all your data is properly initialized before using it.

Comment: Is there a way to find where this is happening? because like i said i think it's in `_vboID` or `_vertNum` but I'm not sure as which or if it's either of those, also those are the only two variables I'm using and they are both initialized

Comment: Did you ever debug the problem? Single step through the instructions and see where the exception is thrown. It is pretty basic programming skills actually.

Answer (score 0):

`GL_VERTEX_ARRAY` is not a valid buffer binding target. What you are looking for is `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`.

When you use `GL_VERTEX_ARRAY` in contexts where a buffer binding target is expected, you should only get a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error, and the calls will have no further effect. As a result, you have no `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` bound during your `glVertexAttribPointer` call, which in a legacy or core profile will result the GL in interpreting your pointers as pointers to client memory.

You should really add some error checks, or use a *debug callback*, so that such simple mistakes can be spotted early.

Comment: ah nice catch, i fixed it but it still gives me an error the message but it's slightly different this time. `Exception thrown at 0x69B3C760 (nvoglv32.dll) in Flora.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.`